# React native Map Without using google map

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, orm

How can I add a free map (not google maps) integration in react native. I don't want to use any google map services or google map.

I have tried Mapbox, leaflet map, openstreet map, and react native map, but all maps are integrated with Google.

Can anyone guide me if there are any free map service alternative to Google map.

Answer (score 0):

For alternatives to react-native-maps , check these npm packages :

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-yandexmapkit
```

Comment: I have already implement in project but this also integrate with Google map.